# How to extract parts of this expression

Tags: regions, mesh

If you look up ImageMesh, it shows how to extract a BoundaryMeshRegion from an image mask. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMesh.html

```
a = ImageMesh[-the example swordfish given for ImageMesh-]
```

This creates a BoundaryMeshRegion.

[image]

I don't understand all the elements of BoundaryMeshRegion, but basically I want to extract the list of points that make up the first part of the expression. I thought I could just do `a[[1]]`, but that doesn't work. I've always had a poor understanding of how to manipulate Mathematica expressions, so my apologies if this is something obvious I should know how to do.

For now I am resorting to turning the Expression into a String, replacing BoundaryMeshRegion with List and then converting back to an Expression. I'm sure this is a very inefficient way to do this and so welcome someone pointing out the correct way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, as said by Documentation, `ImageMesh` generate a result in `BoundaryMeshRegion` form, and `BoundaryMeshRegion` is considered atomic:

```
AtomQ@a
```

> True

So you method of using `Part` will definitely fail.

But there's a special function doing this job, and I think `MeshCoordinates` is what you're finding:

```
MeshCoordinates[a]
```

> {{17.5708, 107.257}, {10.75, 111.25}, {11.7549, 108.436}, {22.5, 
>     100.}, {29.75, 92.75}, {28.3536, 91.3536}, {38., 80.5}, {39.7428, 
>     77.5713}, {38.9644, 69.4987}, {40.4287, 65.7428}, {42.5, 
>     65.}, {43.1682, 65.5291}, {44.5, 73.}, {47.5611, 71.2394}, {64.4, 
>     59.3}, {67.4348, 48.9783}, {69.5659, 49.7519}, {71., 
>     53.5}, {73.4851, 56.8787}, {79.5528, 55.2236}, {82., 52.5}, {89., 
>     51.5}, {90.5, 50.}, {91.5, 37.}, {92.5, 31.}, {93.5, 28.}, {94.5, 
>     26.}, {95.5, 26.}, {96.5, 41.}, {97.8077, 45.4615}, {103.504, 
>     53.062}, {108.485, 56.1213}, {117.125, 58.875}, {114.857, 
>     61.1429}, {102.493, 59.0822}, {96.5003, 55.9822}, {91.4472, 
>     56.7764}, {89.5, 59.}, {88.3536, 63.3536}, {83.584, 
>     64.7226}, {77.6159, 72.3201}, {66.5, 83.}, {64.062, 87.4961}, {65., 
>     90.5}, {69., 94.5}, {71.5, 95.}, {71.5019, 97.9561}, {62.6284, 
>     97.3345}, {52.5003, 94.0167}, {44.5133, 95.1145}, {34.2236, 
>     97.5528}, {30.5088, 98.9064}}

Comment: Ah thanks. I did not know there was such a thing as 'atomic'. That probably explains why I have had trouble with some other results as well.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, an expression with head `BoundaryMeshRegion` is treated as an atomic expression, so `Part` would not work on it directly. But there are workarounds:

```
Uncompress[Compress[a], Hold][[1, 1]]
```

or

```
ToExpression[ToBoxes[a], StandardForm, Hold][[1, 1]]
```

The last approach also works with other atomic expressions that appear to have a structure in `InputForm` or `FullForm`, e.g. `1/2`.

Comment: this is an interesting solution!

Comment: I can use this for other cases where I've had issues. Thanks.

Comment: These are cute, but are at best workarounds.  The first is basically a version of the ToString/ToExpression approach, since Compress creates an nicely compressed string version of the expr.  The second won't work if the StandardForm of the expression isn't interpterable. For example, if a is a SparseArray.  Both create copies of the expression, and generally one of the point of large atomic expressions is avoid such copies.  If an accessor is provided, then that is definitely the way to go (For example, Numerator in the case of Rational).